# maven-antrun spawns process and exits on Windows 7

Tags: java, maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I observe a strange behavior in my build, and I am quite clueless on how to investigate.

During my acceptance tests, I use maven-antrun-plugin on pre-integration-test phase to start the jar that has been built previously. Then fail-safe is supposed to start to run the tests against the jar. I have some existing project for which this works, so I replicated the config :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-application</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <exec executable="cmd" dir="../" spawn="true" os="Windows 7">
                        <arg value="/c"/>
                        <arg value="launcher.bat"/>
                        <arg value="${project.version}"/>
                    </exec>
                    <exec executable="cmd" dir="../" spawn="true" os="Windows Server 2012 R2">
                        <arg value="/c"/>
                        <arg value="launcher.bat"/>
                        <arg value="${project.version}"/>
                    </exec>
                    <exec executable="./launcher.sh" dir="../" os="Linux">
                        <arg value="${project.version}"/>
                    </exec>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
</plugin>
```

However, I see a different behavior. When I do *mvn -X clean install*, on an old project for which it works, I get :

```
[INFO] Executing tasks
Build sequence for target(s) `main' is [main]
Complete build sequence is [main, ]

main:
     [exec] Current OS is Windows 7
     [exec] Executing 'cmd' with arguments:
     [exec] '/c'
     [exec] 'launcher.bat'
     [exec] '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
     [exec]
     [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [exec] not part of the command.
Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'cmd' with arguments:
'/c'
'launcher.bat'
'1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
spawned process java.lang.ProcessImpl@5b6ba5bb
     [exec] Current OS is Windows 7
     [exec] This OS, Windows 7 was not found in the specified list of valid OSes: Windows Server 2012 R2
     [exec] Current OS is Windows 7
     [exec] This OS, Windows 7 was not found in the specified list of valid OSes: Linux
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1:integration-test (default) @ acceptance ---
```

and the tests execute..

Now on my other project, I get this :

```
[INFO] Executing tasks
Build sequence for target(s) `main' is [main]
Complete build sequence is [main, ]

main:
     [exec] Current OS is Windows 7
     [exec] Executing 'cmd' with arguments:
     [exec] '/c'
     [exec] 'launcher.bat'
     [exec] '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
     [exec]
     [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [exec] not part of the command.
Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'cmd' with arguments:
'/c'
'launcher.bat'
'1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.

D:\vincent\GIT\my_project\acceptance>
```

The launcher works, because just like for the other project, my jar gets launched in another window. But then, instead of simply executing the tests with failsafe, **the build simply exits** ! 
The log doesn't show *spawned process java.lang.ProcessImpl@5b6ba5bb* like in the other case.. even though it seems it does spawn the launcher.bat .

I realized I wasn't running exactly the same version of antrun plugin, so I downgraded my new project to 1.7 so that it matches. I am using Java 8 in both cases.

I am really running out of ideas to investigate... Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: You should indicate the Maven version you are using, also show the entire pom.xml for the working and not-working projects.

Comment: Very likely launcher.bat is the culprit .

Comment: thanks a lot @EugenCovaci, your second comment put me on the right track - why it was failing was a pretty dumb reason !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Eugen's comment on my question, I investigated more on the launcher.bat, and replaced the content with a dummy echo/sleep/echo -> my build was now continuing as expected, so I knew I was on the right path.

The content of the launcher.bat is something like this :

```
cd /d %~dp0
echo "killing app before starting it"
call ./kill.bat

start %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java ...blablabla...
```

The kill.bat is supposed to kill the application if it's already running, if it didn't close properly from a previous build for instance.

now, this is the content of kill.bat :

```
wmic process where (commandline like "%%my-app%%" and not name="wmic.exe") delete
```

well, guess what... both the maven build and the app I spawn (I replaced it above with *my-app*) match the where clause - so if my build was not finishing as expected, it's because it was getting killed by the spawned process, which was supposed to kill a previous running version of it, not its "parent" build !

Note : it seems it works on different versions of Windows (like Windows 10) in which probably wmic is slightly different